# Cannot format JSON to .json file properly using JSON.Simple with Java

Tags: java, json

Goal: Append JSONArray data to existing JSONArray in external .json file.

What it should look like:

```
    {"wallPosts": [
            {"userPosts0":[
                {"postText":"This is some post text"},
                {"postUser":"Atloids"},
                {"postDate":"03\/15\/1998"},
                {"postLikes":3}
                ]
            }
          ]
    }
```

What it does after running code the first time:

```
    {"wallPosts": 
            {"userPosts0":[
                {"postText":"This is some post text"},
                {"postUser":"Atloids"},
                {"postDate":"03\/15\/1998"},
                {"postLikes":3}
                ]
            }

    }
```

Error code when ran a 2nd time:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
    at main.Data.main(Data.java:29)

The code:

```
    try {
        String JSON_FILE="/json/data.json";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(JSON_FILE);

        System.out.println(1);
        Object obj = parser.parse(fr);

        System.out.println(2);
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)obj;
        System.out.println(jo);


        System.out.println(3);
        JSONArray wallPostsArray = (JSONArray) jo.get("wallPosts");
        System.out.println(wallPostsArray);


        int numOfWallPosts = wallPostsArray.size();
        System.out.println("Number of Wall Posts: " + numOfWallPosts);

        System.out.println(4);
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        System.out.println(5);
        JSONObject postText = new JSONObject();
        postText.put("postText", "This is some post text");
        JSONObject postUser = new JSONObject();
        postUser.put("postUser", "James Bond");
        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        postData.put("postDate", "07/07/1997");
        JSONObject postLikes = new JSONObject();
        postLikes.put("postLikes", 3);

        System.out.println(6);
        ja.add(postText);
        ja.add(postUser);
        ja.add(postData);
        ja.add(postLikes);

        System.out.println(7);
        JSONObject userPosts = new JSONObject();
        userPosts.put("userPosts"+numOfWallPosts++, ja);


        wallPostsArray.add(userPosts);
        System.out.println(userPosts);

        jo.put("wallPosts", userPosts);
        System.out.println(jo);

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(JSON_FILE);

        file.write(jo.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

        System.out.println(wallPostsArray);
    }
    catch(ParseException e){
        System.out.println("No such file exists.");
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println("No File.");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are different - in the first snippet "wallPosts" is an array of objects (JSONArray), and in the second snippet "wallPosts" is just a JSON object.

when you run it the second time, it errors because "wallPosts" is no longer a JSONArray.

Comment: How would you suggest I keep "wallPosts" as a JSONArray the second time around?

Comment: My suggestion is to model your data as a POJO. Read the file into the POJO, make the updates to the object, then write the object back to a file. 
here is a nice little tutorial from mykong - [How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Jackson)](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson)

Comment: I do not wish to go that route. Do you have any suggestions for my current code?